# Passing props to child component not working

Tags: reactjs

I'm making an axios call and receiving some data, the data is as follows [data is array of json objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oteti.png)

```
[
  {
    "like": 5,
    "_id": "608822d2c6d24d5a2c9b203e",
    "author": "vineeth",
    "punch": "punch1",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "like": 11,
    "_id": "608977a366625258dc62a704",
    "author": "vineeth nice boy",
    "punch": "punch by vineeth",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

I'm looping over the array of data and sending each data element to the child component using map where its expected to render this data . But I'm not able to view/ display data in the child component.

Parent

```
import { useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import Punch from './punch/Punch'
import './Punches.css';
const Punches = ()=> {
  const punches = useSelector((state)=> state.punches);
  console.log(punches);
  return (
    <div className="Punches">
      <div className="card-group">
          {
            punches.map((punch)=>{
              <Punch punch={punch}></Punch>
            })
          }
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  }
export default Punches;
```

Child

```
import './Punch.css';
const Punch =  ({punch})=> {
  console.log(punch);
  return (
      <div className="Punch">
        <h1>{punch}</h1>
      </div>

  )
   
}

export default Punch;
```

Comment: `{punch.punch}`

Comment: Should I pass {punch.punch} the child? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
{
  punches.map((punch) => (<Punch key={punch._id} punch={punch}></Punch>))
}
```

If you add curly braces `{}` for arrow function you have to explicitly return.

and

```
<div className="Punch">
  <h1>{punch.punch}</h1>
</div>
```

here `punch` is a JS object and react doesn't know how to render it as a whole.

[image: Edit awesome-ganguly-w6fxy]